# Swift 4 : custom autocorrect dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I'm currently developing an iOS app with Swift 4. I would like to code a custom autocorrect engine where I use my own words (that are gathered through an API call). For example, on the next picture, I would like to be able to choose all the words that are suggested on the bar above the keyboard. As instance, if my custom dictionary is ["chicken", "chili", "chicago", "cup"], I would like to have the words "chicken", "chili" and "chicago" displayed on the suggestion bar if I type "chi".

[image]

I searched on different websites, and the only solution that I found was to develop a custom keyboard and then to use UILexicon. I'm pretty sure this solution will work but I feel like that it will be a complete waste of time since I'm only interested in a custom autocorrect system, and that I don't need to change the default keyboard appearance and behavior.
Thus, I would like to know if there was a simpler solution to change the dictionary used by the default autocorrect system, or if there was a way to create a custom keyboard inheriting directly from the default one.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 2):

You could look for the words in your dictionary that start with the word typed so far:

```
let array =  ["chicken", "chili", "chicago", "cup"]

let word = "chi"

let filtered = array.filter { $0.hasPrefix(word) }

print(filtered)  //["chicken", "chili", "chicago"]
```

---

AFAIK you can't change the behaviour of the iOS dictionary, nor feed it your own suggestions. You can create a floating view that would look like a suggestions bar (some apps do that), and set `autocorrectionType` to `.no` for the text field/view in your app.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm able to filter words based on their prefix. My question is how to perform such an action and to display the results in the suggestion bar based on what the user is typing in the search bar.

Comment: @AntoineHoorelbeke Have you created a view where to show the suggestions? The question doesn't mention any code that you have tried so far.

Comment: No, my question is if it is possible to override the default dictionary used by the iOS keyboard and to use my own list of words. If it isn't possible to do it easily I'll create my own view above the keyboard to do so.

Comment: Ok thanks, then I'll do that. Sorry if my question wasn't clear